# tescase for javascript code finding closest to zero

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, jasmine

I would like to know what will be the test case for my code..
providing my code below...
how to write test case in jasmine
the code is fully in js...

```
function lowestEpsilon(of) {

    return of.reduce(minimal, [Infinity, Infinity]).shift()

    // pass around a pair of [value, Math.abs(value)] and replace
    // it if the current item has a better absolute value.
    function minimal(previously, value) {
        var absolute = Math.abs(value)
        if ( absolute < previously[1] )
            return [value, absolute]
        return previously
    }
}

lowestEpsilon([1,2,-0.5])

lowestEpsilon([50,0.3,-0.2,1,50])
```

Comment: Hi, can you edit to clarify what your question is? (It looks like you already have two test cases at the bottom.)

Comment: @KevinChen: jasmine test case i need to write..thanks for ur reply..

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what your test names or classes should be, but here is the basic outline you would use in Jasmine to write the two test cases you specified.

```
describe("my tests", function () {

    it("case 1", function () {
        var low = lowestEpsilon([1, 2, -0.5]);
        expect(low).toBe(0.5);
    });

    it("case 2", function () {
        var low = lowestEpsilon([50, 0.3, -0.2, 1, 50])
        expect(low).toBe(0.2);
    });
});
```